# Sub-Schemas in SQL Server 2005/2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, design-patterns, schema

This is a simple question yet I was unable to find any information at all about this.

**Is it possible to have sub-schemas in SQL Server 2005/2008?**

*Example:*
Having a HR (Human Resources) schema with a sub-schema called Training (with tables related to this). It would end up like `HR.Training.*` where `*` would be the tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You could fake this with roles by putting different users into different roles and allowing those roles to use objects.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could fake it in the naming of the schema, like HR_Training.* and HR_Reviews.* and so forth. Cheesy, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Are you coming from an Oracle background by any chance ? Oracle has the concept of Schemas I believe. In SQL Server the closest equivalent is a Database.

You can cross-query from one database to another on the same SQL server very easily and that would give you virtually the same kind of calling syntax

e.g server.database.owner.object

In you case it might look like HRSvr.HR.dbo.xxx and HRSvr.Training.dbo.xxxx.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't know that.
I didn't come from a Oracle background but I did study it some time ago.

Comment: actually "owner" seems to these days also be called schema, or maybe schema owner ? I am a bit out of touch with the latest / greatest SQL server terminology but I am sure this is well documented in books online. Anyhow, there are a number of ways to achieve what you want I think.

Comment: MS SQL has schemas too, and since MS SQL 2005, these are not the same as owners / users, although they can be related if needed.

Comment: Your recommendation is solid. However, if you are encrypting data in any of your databases, you will find it extra challenging to compare and join data on encrypted columns as the values will be unavailable to the SQL server. Some basic operations are supported, but you will start running into cross-boundary issues.

Answer (score 1):

yea you can make schemas but doesn't seem like you can make sub-schemas.  I come from IBM db2 background but our IT folks here don't seen to know that you can other schemas beside the default 'dbo'.